# how can i add filter to my pivot table with vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

Using VBA code, I have created a Pivot table and then added row, columns and values.Now I need to add  filters.
Can you please let me know how can I add filters?

I have a VBA code that need to loop over Pivot Table with filters.
so far:

```
     'Add item to the Report Filter- chose the filter that you want
     pvt.PivotFields("DB").Orientation = xlPageField
     'Position Item in list
     pvt.PivotFields("DB").Position = 1
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while you add a filter manually to see what code gets generated?

Comment: i need a second filter and looping:pvt.PivotFields("de_em").Orientation = xlPageField .    the variable de_em  has to values(0 and 1)

Comment: Then why don't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add filter to a pivot table that I know of.

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable

Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") 

'Adds to the Report Filter
pvt.PivotFields("DB").Orientation = xlPageField

'Adds to the Column Labels
pvt.PivotFields("DB").Orientation = xlColumnField

'Adds to the Row Labels
pvt.PivotFields("DB").Orientation = xlRowField
```

Comment: i think i need to use something like that:  For Each cell In                  pvt.PivotFields("de_em")
   
   Next cell                            but i dont know how